# "Stick it to the man!" Mathematical discoveries that resulted in persecution.

Tags: soft-question, math-history, big-list

As the old story goes, Pythagoras and his followers were adamant that all numbers were rational, until Hippasus came along and proved that $\sqrt{2}$ (the length of the diagonal of the unit square) is irrational. A lot of Pythagoras' work was thrown into question, and as a result, he sentenced Hippasus to be drowned.

Now, I'm dubious of the reliability of this story (it varies from source to source), but I *am* interested in whether there are more cases of a mathematician being persecuted (punished in some way) by "the man" for making a radical discovery/proof.

Are there any such examples? If there are, please state the discovery (the actual mathematical statement) along with the punishment.

**Edit**

I'm looking for examples of persecution **solely due to the discovery** (not anything to do with the race, relgion, orientation, etc. of the discover**er**)

Comment: Earth is not flat. Not strictly mathematical though.

Comment: @UserX But that's a case of us forgetting something we already knew (by solving math problems), and then defending a naive revision created in ignorance (to solve a political problem).

Comment: @UserX And who, as far as we know, [first penned that down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Heavens)? Were they persecuted for that?

Comment: Galileo was persecuted by the Roman Catholic Church for the discoveries he made from his telescope, though this was not a mathematical discovery so it does not fit your request.

Comment: German mathematicians who were Jewish were forced out of their positions by the Nazis. Landau in particular was boycotted by his students under the guise that his particular "style" of mathematics was unsuited to the classroom in Germany.

Comment: @KCd: Good point. Also Schur had to quit his position, too. Hausdorff was persecuted as well, and eventually committed suicide to avoid the camps. Although none of them were persecuted for their discoveries. Just for their religion.

Comment: See the story by Anna Varvak (currently the top-ranked one) among the answers to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53122/mathematical-urban-legends

Comment: Did you watch School of Rock? :)

Comment: Somehow I can only come up with examples the other ways round: People got arrested and thus had enough "spare time" do develop theories ...

Comment: [Number theory helped Pal Turan avoid persecution](http://unimodular.net/blog/?p=240).

Comment: Community Wiki?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Israel Gelfand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Gelfand) discovered the [tridiagonal matrix algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm) (or rather established its stability and applied to numerical solution of PDEs) in the early 50s . In view of the main applications of numerical analysis at that time the method - essentially an elementary linear algebra - was classified by the Soviet government services and Gelfand was forbidden to leave the country. Being a major mathematician of the epoch, he was therefore unable to participate in any conference abroad until (?) the late 70s.

Answer (score 17):

For his mathematical achievements, Cantor was ostracized by the mathematical community.  Instead of being given the professorship he deserved, he ended up teaching in what was effectively a community college.  He slowly went insane after that.

Describing the mathematics of Cantor, Poincare is famously quoted as saying that "later generations will regard Mengenlehre (set theory) as a disease from which one has recovered".

Source:  http://topdocumentaryfilms.com/dangerous-knowledge/

Comment: There is not strong evidence that Poincaré actually said this. [Here's an article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03024067) discussing the quote.

Comment: While some people "stuck branches" into Cantor's wheels, he was not at all ostracized. Many influential mathematicians saw in set theory an interesting subject, and he did publish some work. He also didn't "slowly went insane", he suffered from depression, from which he recovered for some time and published more papers, later to sink into it again.

Comment: @Asaf Your first sentence is your own interpretation. For sure  Kronecker did ostracize him; also see "An Episodic History of Mathematics" (Steven Krantz) which specifically mentions ostracism .

Comment: @AsafKaragila I would also say that a man who goes into depression recovers and later sinks into it again could be described as "slowly went insane".

Comment: @Ganesh: Then I ostracize you. Does that mean that you are being ostracized? It seems that the reasonable interpretation is not that a few mathematicians ignored and overlooked someone, but that the majority of the mathematical community, at the time, shunned that person away. This is clearly not what happened with Cantor.

Comment: @NicNic8: No, it doesn't. "Slowly went insane" is a broad, unclear, and quite frankly insulting to anyone who ever knew someone close that suffered from depression. Not to mention that clinical depression, being one of the modern world's most common diseases does not really count as "going insane", or else we're all insane, in which case the definition of sanity is meaningless to begin with. "Slowly went insane" hints, somehow, something more akin to onset schizophrenia, or other psychotic disorder. Not depression.

Comment: @AsafKaragila , There was also a book reference in my comment, which too you have ostracized. It seems clear that you have ostracized everything but your own opinion of what happened to Cantor.  Thanks for your reaction, anyhow.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, Thanks, you too buddy.

Comment: Cantor's work was disagreed with by proponents of constructive set theory, a number of whom (such as Kronecker) were quite influential. Kronecker's particular influence at the University of Berlin prevented Cantor from achieving a professorship there. Ostracization by "*the mathematical community*" is certainly a sweeping overgeneralization. I will not address issues of his sanity or lack thereof.

Comment: I would point out, though, that "post hoc, ergo propter hoc" is a fallacy.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a rather comical one.

Henry Oldenburg founded the Royal Society (in London) in 1662.

If an effort to publish high quality papers, he had to correspond with many foreigners across Europe. The high volume of foreign correspondence came to the attention of authorities.  He was arrested as a spy and held in the Tower of London for several months.

Comment: And, more recently, Andre Weil was arrested by the Finnish police in 1940 on a suspicion of being a Soviet spy.

Comment: And Rokhlin was arrested by Soviet police on suspicion of being a German spy and spend about 2 years in GULAG. None of this is comical, of course.

Comment: @studiosus: neither of those examples are people being persecuted for their work, as the original question had asked.

Comment: @KCd: Weil's case was nearly identical to the one described by Nick, with suspicious papers being mathematical correspondence between Weil and Kolmogorov.

Comment: @studiosus IIRC, the Fins were so scared of the Sowiets that they supported _Nazi Germany_, which was strong enough to fight the USSR (they hoped). (Of course, they weren't, in the end.)

Comment: @studiosus: I reread Weil's autobiography. He wrote that he was brought to jail in Finland simply for looking like a foreigner while standing near some military equipment. Later the police searched his apartment and found among the incriminating evidence a letter in Russian from Pontryagin, not Kolmogorov. Considering Weil's interest in topological groups, it makes sense that he corresponded with Pontryagin rather than Kolmogorov.

Comment: From Weil's autobiography I learned that Lie had been arrested in Paris in 1870 soon after the start of the Franco-Prussian war for possibly being a spy because his work habit of taking notes in the forest was suspicious. See the end of http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1899-05-07/S0002-9904-1899-00628-1/S0002-9904-1899-00628-1.pdf for more on this episode.

Comment: This answer seems very off-topic.

Comment: @JiK I can see why you might think that, since we do not today associate the Royal Society with mathematics.  However the association was strong at the time.  Oldenburg's was appointed to the task of Foreign Correspondent, and he corresponded with many famous mathematicians of the day, such as Leibniz and Mersenne.  He therefore was persecuted for his work.

Comment: @NickR Then please state the discovery (the actual mathematical statement) along with the punishment.

Comment: JiK has a valid point: all of these are stories of bad things that happened to people as a result of the _process_ of their mathematical work, not as a result of any outcome of the work.

Comment: Weil was, indeed, arrested by the Finnish police for taking a walk near a military establishment while being a foreigner. His host, Nevanlinna (whose pro-German views gave him some troubles post war), intervened on his behalf. And, yes @columbus, Finland "supported" *Germany* in the sense that when Barbarossa began we joined in to regain the territory annexed by the USSR 1½ years earlier. There were not too many other sizable nations willing to support a war effort against the Soviets. We would have gladly accepted other offers as well. Shit happens, when you are small :-)

Answer (score 1):

There was an acerbic dispute between David Hilbert and L.E.J. Brouwer in the beginning of the 20th century. Basically, the former found the latter's insistence on constructivist methods ever more annoying. The animosity had eventually led to Brouwer's isolation within the scientific community. Brouwer survived his exile by almost forty years and died at an old age—in a car accident.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit the other way around (someone persecuted who found refuge in his own mind) : Jacow Trachtenberg developed a method for doing arithmetics while being held in a nazi camp.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trachtenberg_system

Comment: As pointed out in the comments to the main questions, there were severely mathematicians which had to endure hardships from the Nazi regime. It's not quite what the question is asking, though.

Comment: @vajra78, Agreed, my bad, deleted the comment.

Comment: Similarly, Desargues famously developed projective geometry while a prisoner of war in Russia between 1812 and 1814.

Comment: @MJD It was quite remarkable for Desargues to do so, too, since at that time he'd been dead for over 150 years.

Comment: I think you meant Poncelet ... :-)

Comment: That is who I meant.  Thanks for the correction.